# HTML vertical center selection when option is selected in an HTML selection list

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following HTML code:

```
<select name="" id="listF" size="10">
        <option value="01">001</option>
        <option value="02">002</option>
        <option value="03">003</option>
        <option value="04">004</option>
        <option value="05">005</option>
        <option value="06">006</option>
        <option value="07">007</option>
        <option value="08">008</option>
        <option value="09">009</option>
        <option value="10">010</option>
        <option value="11">011</option>
        <option value="12">012</option>
        <option value="13">013</option>
        <option value="14">014</option>
        <option value="15">015</option>
        <option value="16">016</option>
        <option value="17">017</option>
        <option value="18">018</option>
        <option value="19">019</option>
        <option value="20">020</option>
        <option value="21">021</option>
        <option value="22">022</option>
        <option value="23">023</option>
        <option value="24">024</option>
    </select>
```

And I have the following JavaScript

```
$('#listF').click(function(){
    var n = 10;
    if(this.selectedIndex < ($(this).find('option').length-n)) {
    this.selectedIndex+=n;
    this.selectedIndex-=n;
    }
});
```

The HTML lenght of the select is 10 - I would like that whenever I choose an option it is vertically centerered (not horizontally) say it will be displayed the 5th e.g.

```
Option 1 
Option 2
Option 3
Option 4
Option 5
Option 6
Option 7
Option 8
Option 9
Option 10
```

If I choose option 12 - option 12 will be centered

```
Option 8
Option 9
Option 10
Option 11
Option 12 <<<<<Centered
Option 13
Option 14
Option 15
Option 16
Option 17
```

Say I choose option 7 - option 7 will be centered

```
Option 3
Option 4
Option 5
Option 6
Option 7 <<<<<Centered
Option 8
Option 9
Option 10
Option 11
Option 12
```

How can I modiy my javascript to achive this?

I want to vertically center an `<option>` relatively to the `<select>`

Comment: You want to vertically center an `<option>` relatively to the `<select>`?

Comment: Exactly. How do I go about it please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BA39h/1/)

```
$('#listF').on('change', function(){
    var n = this.getAttribute('size'),
        i = this.selectedIndex,
        l = this.options.length;
    this.selectedIndex = Math.min(l-1, i+n/2|0);
    this.selectedIndex = Math.max(0, i+1-n/2|0);
    this.selectedIndex = i;
});
```

Tested with both odd and even sizes.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. How can I change the above _$('#listF').on('change', function(){_ if I have more than two lists please? I tried $('#listF' && '#listX').on('change', function(){ but it didn't work

Comment: @user3173207 Try `$('#listF, #listX').on('change'`